# Error in grepl(pattern, df): invalid regular expression

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, grepl

I've been trying to search for a specific pattern within a column.
My pattern is a quite big list of words(>2000) and the column to screen has millions of rows (df$column1)

I've created my pattern using a column from a different dataframe

```
word<-df2$words_to_use
pattern<-paste0('.*',word,'.*', collapse ='|')
```

so my pattern looks like (>2000 words):

```
.* word1.* | .* word2.* | .* word3.* | .* word4.*
```

I want to create a Y/N columns in df that says if df$column1 contains any of the words in the pattern.

to do that I've used

```
df$check<-ifelse(grepl(pattern,df$column1),'Y','N')
```

it works fine for small patterns but for bigger ones I receive the error message

```
Error in grepl(pattern,df$column1):invalid regular expression
```

Thank you very much if you will be able to help me!

Comment: Do your words from `df2$words_to_use` contain special chars like `(` or `[`?

Comment: No, it doesn't contain any ( or [

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are lots of elements, instead of `paste`ing together, loop over the  pattern vectors with `lapply` and `Reduce`

```
ifelse(Reduce(`|`, lapply(word, function(pat) grepl(pat, df$column1))), "Y", "N")
```